# getting Unrecognized selector crash on Mac OSx. When I try to close the sheet while textfield is getting edited

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

If I end the sheet while editing the textfield I get unrecognised selector error. But if I hit TAB after completing the editing the sheet closes fine.please help me I have tried many things such as unselecting etc but not able t get the solution.

[image: problem details and system configuration]
[image: stack trace]

[image: I have to manually click somewhere or press a TAB to stop the editing]

```
- (id)  tableView:(NSTableView *) aTableView   o bjectValueForTableColumn:NSTableColumn *) aTableColumn row:(int) rowIndex {    NSString *result = nil;
    CellIp *ipElement =  (CellIp*)[workIPArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *identifier = (NSString*)[aTableColumn identifier];
    switch([identifier intValue]){
        case 1:
            result = [ipElement getCellIp];
            break;
        case 2:
            result = [ipElement getCellComment];
            break;

    return result;  
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OPxo.png
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? It's often usefull.

Comment: Judging by the crash log it looks like you are _not_ running the app from Xcode. That should be step 1, the debugger will give you more info. When the app crashes Xcode should have a message about what the unrecognized selector is and an address of what instance it was sent to. _Leave the app running_ and use `po` followed by the address of the instance (should start with `0x`). That will tell you what kind of thing it is. Then use the variables view to id which specific thing (like the tableview, etc.) is causing the issue. Then update your question with that info.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am new to the objective c and Xcode, I have imported the code and able to build it successfully in Xcode. But the PreferencePane does not come up after I run the source code.

Comment: The table column indices are 1 and 2?  Looks like 0 and 1 to me in the screenshot, which makes the switch statement not do what it's supposed to do.